# Access server from anywhere without public IP and/or Port forwarding

Tags: server, ip, router, portforwarding

Currently we have a home Internet connection with a public static IP, 100up10down for 60$/m, since we got a really good offer 500down100up for 12$/m we are going to switch internet provider. The catch, the new provider does not offer public IP and/or Port forwarding.

I have one home server and one server in a Datacenter.
Is there a solution for me to route traffic through my "public" server to my home server?
I have root access (obviously) to both server, is there something that I could install on my datacenter server that routes traffic to my private server?

I thought maybe there is something (software) where my private server connects to port 1234 on my datacenter server and if the datacenter server receives data on port 1234 it forwards it to my private server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for port forwarding services.

https://portmap.io/

There are other ones that I can’t find right now.

Comment: thanks a lot, why is this so hard to find? googled for half an hour :(
do you know about a solution without an external provider, basically portmaps.ios software, which i can install on my server?

Comment: for anyone looking, this is basically portmap.io selfhosted and opensource: https://github.com/antoniomika/sish